# FullCalendar overnight recurring events & Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I'd like to post a question about FullCalendar overnight recurring events. As far as I understand the only way to do it looks like this:

```
[
  start: '09:00am',
  end: '27:00pm',
  dow: [1]
]
```

Is there a better approach to this problem and if not what's the easiest / fastest way to calculate the end time in Ruby on Rails having the start and the end datetimes?
Obviously just adding the difference between 2 dates to the start date won't work cause it'll be considered as the next day.
I've tried doing something like this but that's very ugly and impractical:

```
hours, minutes = start_datetime.strftime('%H:%m').split(':').map(&:to_i)
hours_diff, min_diff = ((end_datetime - start_datetime) / 1.hour).round
end_datetime = "#{hours + hours_diff}:#{minutes}"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing this with moment.js which is bundled with the fullcalendar? Btw 27:00pm seems incorrect, should be just '27:00'.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about '27:00', it's a typo. Regarding your question - yes, I did, however moment.js considers 27:00 to be invalid date and increases the day by 1 as well